# How to find intersection of two lines in parametric form?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, analytic-geometry

I want to find the intersection of $ \mathrm L(x,y) = 3x + 4y - 8 = 0$ and $\mathrm M(x,y) = 2x - 5y + 3 = 0$.

Let parametric form of $\rm L$ is $\mathbf Q(t) = \vec a + t(-4, 3)$ and $\mathbf R(t) = \vec a + t(5, 2)$ be the parametric form of $\mathrm M$. $\vec a$ is the intersection of both lines.

If I put $\mathbf Q(t_0) = \mathbf R(t_0)$ then I get $t_0 = 0$. How do I find $\vec a$ from this ? If I put $t_0$ back in either of the $\bf Q$ or $\bf R$ I will get $\mathbf {R}(t_0) = \mathbf Q(t_0) = \vec a$, which is not very helpful.

I know the intersection is $\bigg(\dfrac {84}{69}, \dfrac {25}{23}\bigg)$.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Yes I can solve the system but I want the intersection when lines are int their parametric form.

Comment: The parametric forms with unknown $\vec{a}$ are not very helpful. Take $\vec{a}_1+t(-4,3)$ and $\vec{a}_2+s(5,2)$ instead, where $\vec{a}_1$ and $\vec{a}_2$ are some *known* points on the lines. For example, $\vec{a}_1=(0,2)$, $\vec{a}_2=(1,1)$.

Comment: what should be $$\vec{a}$$?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner The intersection of two lines.

Comment: this is not right, $$\vec{a}$$ must be vector to a Point of the line

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner But the intesection, by definition will be on the line.

Comment: this will be on both and must computed

Comment: @A.Γ. If $\mathbf Q(t) = (0,2) + t(-4, 3)$ and $\mathbf R(t) = (1,1) + t(5, 2)$. Then if I substract $\bf R$ and $\bf Q$ I get $0 = (-1, 1) + t(-9, 1)$. Which I has no solution in $t$ I guess.

Comment: you must denote the other paramter with $s$ for example

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner $\mathbf Q(t) = (0,2) + t(-4, 3)$ and $\mathbf R(s) = (1,1) + s(5, 2)$ ??

Comment: @123 Then you need to solve the system $Q(t)=R(s)$ (note the different parameters). Here you have two unknowns $s,t$ and two equations (two coordinates). There is no easier way.

Comment: @A.Γ. Not really much useful than just solving the system of equations in normal form. Thanks anyway.

Comment: To sum up, you have to use different parameters for the two lines since there’s no reason to believe that the intersection will occur at the same value of the parameter, which is what you wrote. BTW, the direct way to compute the intersection of the two lines is to compute their cross product (in homogeneous coordinates); no solving of equations required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must solve the system of equations:
$$\begin{cases}-4t=1+5s \\
3+2t=1+2s\end{cases}$$

Comment: thank you for editing my post!